# AWS EC2: How to check disk size and usage from Dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon Web Services and can see my EC2 instances in the dashboard. I would like to see the **size** of the attached disk for each one and how much **unused space** I have left. I know that I can ssh into each instance and run `df` if I wanted to.

**How would I get this information through the EC2 dashboard**?

Here is the dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to see these metrics from this. They would instead be a custom metric against each EBS volume.

Take a look at the CloudWatch agent that should be installed on your EC2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

Comment: In the dashboard, I can see (1) EC2 instances, (2) EBS volumes, and (3) attachments. However, I can't see any information that associates an EC2 instance to a volume. Is there any way I can EC2-to-volume information directly or indirectly?

Comment: I know this is a pretty good solution, but when I first encountered this, my first thought was hey there is no way that aws isn't providing memory and disk metrics by default :/

Comment: Its because AWS only reports on host level metrics to protect the privacy of the data stored. Volumes have a property named "Attachment information" within the console.

The custom metric will report the instance name as well as instance id, to view this information you can programatically list the EBS volumes on each instance under block storage: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Answer (score 4):

EC2 tools or the Management Console don't have that higher level of access to EBS volume (i.e. at the file system level) So, there is no way to determine how much data or free space is available within a volume from outside an OS, except by invoking a command within the OS where the volume is mounted.

Answer (score 3):

On the console, you can see the files in the system here: 
Go to AWS System Manager > Node Management > Fleet Manager > 
Choose the EC2 you want to see the filesystem. 
Check /dev folder. 
But still can't see the volume size. 

To see volume size: 
Go to EC2 > Volumes on console. 
Choose the volume, click on Volume ID.
Check the 'Attached Instances'. Note the device path (/dev/xvdcg).

Click the instance name. 
You will see the instance to which this volume is attached.
[find your volume and click Volume ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6pAn.png)

[Note volume path and connect to the instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Z6R.png)

Connect to that instance and run this command inside:

> $ sudo df -hT device_path # i.e df -hT /dev/xvdcg

You will see the size and used

> Filesystem     Type    Size    Used   Avail.  Use%.  Mounted on 
> /dev/nvme1n1  ext4  252G  252G     0 100% /var/lib/../aws/eu-west-1b/vol-xxxxx003

Comment: The part starting from `To see volume size:` to the end is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for the first question: **How to find the disk size from the dashboard**. However, I can't figure out a way to get the disk's remaining unused space from this UI.

1. Click on instance

[image]

2. Click on root device

[image]

3. Click on EBS volume ID

[image]

4. See the disk size

[image]

If anyone can determine how to get unused disk space from the dashboard, please post your answer.